# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am getting this error when calling my php script from ubuntu server. I have installed php5-pgsql using apt get but the error is still persisting. Below is my source code, kindly assist.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$host = "localhost";
$port = "5432";
$user = "postgres";
$pass = "root";
$db = "quickbed";

$con = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Could not connect to server\n");

$query = "select * from tbl_hosts, (select count(*) from tbl_hosts) as cnt order by registration_time";
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

$rows['spaces']  = pg_fetch_all($rs);

echo json_encode($rows);
pg_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled the module in your ini file?

Comment: Take a look at the output of the `phpinfo()` function and search for the extension. Most likely it failed to load.

Comment: the php.ini file located in /etc/php5/apache2 do not have those modules but i have added them manually i.e extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll. However, I have uncommented those modules on ini file located in /etc/php/7.0/apache2

Comment: you need to enable this also `extension="pgsql.so"`

Comment: @G.Joe In the *nix OS you must use '.so' files (not '.*dll')

Answer (score 2):

You must install the PostgreSQL module and enable it.
http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php

Comment: Thanks Neodan, this is what i was missing; php7.0-pgsql